# When I initialize app firebase in void main() its throws an error for the web but its works fine with android

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-web

[image: Error]

When I initialize app firebase in void main() its throws an error for the web but its works fine with android.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "test[enter image description here][1]",
      theme: MyTheme.lightTheme,
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => LoginPage(),
        MyRoutes.home: (context) => HomePage(),
        MyRoutes.login: (context) => LoginPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the necessary scripts to your index.html file? See https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  . Good luck 

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the script tag for firebase in your index.html file

```html
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    <!-- Add this line -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can check the docs here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/web